Azure Cosmos Gremlin Graph Can't find newly created graph
I have some scripts that have been connecting to Azure's CMDB Gremlin Graph (systems) for some time with no problem. using a generic g.V().count() to verify.

I just added stagingsystems and can't seem to get a connection.
Returns the error
ExceptionType : NotFoundException
ExceptionMessage : Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException : Response status code does not indicate success: NotFound (404); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: ***; Reason: (
code : NotFound
message : Message: {"Errors":["Resource Not Found. Learn more: https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-not-found"]}

Both of the two graphs are in the same location, same instance, and in the same graphdb. So the only thing that I'm changing should be
from: username = '/dbs/graphdb/colls/systems'
to: username = '/dbs/graphdb/colls/stagingsystems'
The endpoint and the key should be the same. Data from systems not from stagingsystems. Checked the spelling.

Error says that the newly created graph "stagingsystems" cannot be located, means that there is a discrepancy in the resource path or that the graph was not successfully established.

I suggest editing to show a [mcve]. Right now all you provided was a single setting, with no code, no data... really nothing to go on.

An example would be here: client.submitAsync("g.V().count()") However it's not the query that is the issue. Per @Balaji It looks liek the second graph is routed in a different path or something.
